# VS Code 3rd Party Intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I am using the latest release build of VS Code (1.13.1) and I am having some issues with the IntelliSense when trying to use 3rd party libraries.

My example is using JQuery, I have installed JQuery via NPM and imported this into my main.ts file. according to the VS Code website, the IntelliSense should automatically pick up common libraries and display functions and members that are available to that language, so when I type $ and click the '.' key I should see "ajax" for example. I can get the IntelliSense working by installing the types in NPM (npm install @types/jquery).

Am I doing something wrong that might be stopping the automated process from occuring?

Many thanks
Stuart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code Intellisense not working for NPM package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780700/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working-for-npm-package)