# Visual Studio Code Intellisense not working for NPM package

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.20.0 on Windows. My intellisense is not working correctly eg: visual studio code is not able to detect that the youtubedl package has getinfo method. Would the community have inputs on what I need to do to get intellisense working correctly? If not, how can I browse an NPM package to find the various methods exposed by it(In .Net we can do the same using an object explorer)?

[image]

Comment: I am having same problem and creating a jsconfig.json file did not helped. Following some docs, I found out, I can see the TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features that as from the githib repository  is bundled with Visual Studio Code( or should )

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ES6 imports, you'll [need a `jsconfig.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_what-is-jsconfigjson) in the root of your project.

Below is an example config, with `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` being the important option that will [likely solve your problem](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense-is-not-working-for-external-libraries).

Don't forget to restart VSCode afterwards.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
}
```

Comment: Even after have added the jsconfig.json I still have the question problem

Comment: Somehow after a couple of times closing and opening Typescript it started to work, so I wondering it was the lack of this jsconfig.json

Comment: Its dissapointing that this is not the default behaviour. If you're using typescript, you need to add a different code snippet to the tsconfig.json file too.

Comment: I've spent countless hours on this issue and this is what worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I'm also meet the same problem. And I'm using VS Code v1.24.0 on the macOS High Sierra.

referred from the page: `https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_fixing-npm-not-installed-warning-for-automatic-type-acquisition`.
VS Code automatically downloads and manages the type declaration files(*.d.ts) for JS with the ATA(Automatic Type Acquisition) feature, but it also not works for me.

So I find this:
`https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped`. we can download the type declaration files manually with this kind command:

`npm install --save-dev @types/name_for_the_ package`

and you can choose to use the extension [Types auto installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jvitor83.types-autoinstaller) in VS Code to help you download type declaration files when you run `npm install`. maybe sometimes the `Types auto installer` will also not work, but you can download the types file manually anyway.

after you install the types files, you will get the intellisense again.

[image]

> For the most part, type declaration packages should always have the same name as the package name on npm, but prefixed with @types/, but if you need, you can check out http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/ to find the package for your favorite library.
>
> > [TypeScript-Declaration Files-Consumption](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html)

In some situation, you may need to add a `jsconfig.json` file to your project.

> The presence of a jsconfig.json file in a directory indicates that the directory is the root of a JavaScript project. jsconfig.json specifies the root files and the options for the language features provided by the JavaScript language service. For common setups a jsconfig.json file is not required, however, there are situations when you will want to add a jsconfig.json.
>
> > Not all files should be in your JavaScript project (for example, you want to exclude some files from showing IntelliSense). This situation is common with front-end and back-end code.
> >
> > Your workspace contains more than one project context. In this situation, you should add a jsconfig.json file at the root folder for each project.(the jsconfig.json can have no content.)
> >
> > You are using the TypeScript compiler to down-level compile JavaScript source code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Ubuntu 18.04 and :

VSC as following

Version: 1.40.1
Commit: 8795a9889db74563ddd43eb0a897a2384129a619
Date: 2019-11-13T16:49:30.162Z
Electron: 6.1.2
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-70-generic snap

Considering that contrary of what docs says:

[Working with JavaScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript)

TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features is not listed under the extensions

What did made the intelligent code completion for Javascript was this 2 interdipendent steps:

- create jsconfing.json
- disable the "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly" default extention

Of course restart the VSC

Answer (score 0):

It might not be your case, but in mine it was fairly straightforward. I installed an npm package and for some reason VS Code's language service didn't  pick it up, so autocompletion was not working for that package.

Restarting VS Code had the Intellisense autocompletion be refreshed.